# mongoDB Error: pymongo.errors.Server.SelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, mongodb

This is my code:

```
import sys
 import random
 import pymongo
 from pymongo import MongoClient

def delDB():
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client.words_database

    client.drop_database(db)

    self._ensure_opened()

if__name__=="main":
    delDB()
```

This results in the following error:

> Error: pymongo.errors.Server.SelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

MongoDB is definitely installed.

Comment: `Connection refused` means the operating system active rejected the connection because there is nothing listed on the requested port.

Comment: OK. I have nothing in the database, so do you think that's it?

Comment: No, it means no running process is bound to port 27017.

Comment: OK. I'll see about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No running process was bound to port 27017. Fixed.